# How to solve this database connection error?

Tags: mysql, database

Deprecated:mysql_connect(): the MySQL extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead                             How to remove this errors???

Comment: Its already mentioned in the error `use mysqli or PDO instead`!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question as stated actually includes the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set this code on the top of your pages.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors',1 );
```